# QGIS throws errors in Project after updating to QGIS 3.20

Tags: qgis, error, update, qgs

After updating QGIS in Version 3.20.3-Odense, I get following three errors when opening projects that were running without problems before.

> -Loading layer fnk_get: Font “Dingbats” not available on system

> -Cannot use project transform between EPSG:31467 and EPSG:25832

> -Cannot use project transform between EPSG:5677 and EPSG:25832

I do not use dingbats anywhere nor the projections 5677 and 31467. Who can help?

Comment: You can maybe have more info on what's going on by extract (zip) the project file `.qgz` and open with a text editor the project file `.qgs`, search for `Dingbats` or `31467`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Dingbats, in my case, the problem comes when I use a Font Marker My solution was: in Font Marker change Font MS Shell Dlg 2 to MS Serif.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue with symbology and CRS are unrelated but solution by @RBenet worked for me as long as I applied the change in the general symbol settings rather than just in the categorized symbol settings (if using categorized symbols)